# Event log entry when moving service or application to another node

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-cluster

I have a windows Server 2008 R2 cluster and I would like to be able to distinguish between a user initiated failover and a failover caused be a resource check failing.

I was hoping that the cluster service would write this information to the event log; but it appears this is not occurring. is there any way to make the cluster service write an event to the event log when a failover occurs?

Answer (score 0):

How to create the cluster.log in Windows Server 2008 Failover Clustering

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2008/09/24/8962934.aspx

Comment: I need to check and see whether the log contains this information. I was hoping for something that would write directly to either the application or system event log.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late...

You can use this event IDs for monitoring when services move to another node

Event ID 1200 is the cluster trying to come online.
Event ID 1201 is the cluster comming online.
Event ID 1203 is the cluster trying to go offline.
Event ID 1204 is the cluster comming offline.